How to hide environment variable in Airflow DAG's log?
I am using Airflow to periodically run a query on an Oracle server. The connection string is defined in an Airflow variable called password_oracle_connections, so that it remains secret.
The DAG instantiates a Docker image, for which it defines an OS variable called PASSWORD_CX:
dag_task_name = "Oracle_Monitoring"
with DAG(dag_task_name, default_args=default_args, catchup=False) as dag:
    task1 = DockerOperator(
        task_id=dag_task_name,
        image="repo.cargo.fr:8444/ass/airflow-oracle-monitoring:v0.1.0",
        command='/bin/bash -c \'printenv; \
                                echo "=== My context ==="; \
                                ls -l /app; \
                                echo "=================="; \
                                python /app/oracle_monitor.py\'',
        auto_remove=True,
        xcom_all=True,
        tty=True,
        force_pull=True,
        environment={
            "TEST": "test",
            "PASSWORD_CX": "{{ var.value.password_oracle_connections}}"
        }
    )

It works as expected, but the OS variable remains visible in the DAG's log!
[2024-05-31, 14:40:46 UTC] {docker.py:373} INFO - PASSWORD_CX=[{

    "context": "DEV-INTS1: LCDE",

    "user": "MONITOR_ADMIN_USER",

    "password": "vY2J2XEgE$3NX*$#Fb7T!7as",

    "server": "INTS1_SRV"

}]

How can I hide this, or change the log level for this DAG only?

I finally found out that Jinja templates do not take in consideration the confidential aspect of a variable (based on its name including the "password" string).
The solution is to use the Variable.get() method:
    from airflow.models import Variable
    environment={
        "TEST": "test",
        "PASSWORD_CX": Variable.get("oracle_monitoring_password")
    }

Then in the DAG's log, the variable content is replaced by "***".
